# Share image to Facebook (IOS app/Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

pls help. I have not made an update to my app in over a year. Now I tried to add a button to share an image to Facebook. But the button will not don't work. In general, nothing happens after pressing on it. How can I fix it ?

Best regards,
 Ivan (yeah yeah my english is poor)

```
-(void)shareWithFacebook{

NSLog(@"fb");
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
{
    SLComposeViewController *fbSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                           composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [fbSheet setInitialText:@"Document from Docement scanner"];
    [fbSheet addImage:self.savedImage];
    [self presentViewController:fbSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
}
```

Comment: Let's clarify: `NSLog(@"fb");` is called (printed)? `[SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]` returns `YES`?

Comment: I am guessing, that you have a (void) instead of (IBAction). are u sure this method is linked to the button that you added?

Comment: @GaneCode yes i'm sure